# Prove that every matrix in $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$ is a product of matrices of these four kinds

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We know that every matrix in $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$ is a scalar multiple because of the isomorphism between $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C)/(\mathbb{C}^*)I_2$.

There are four kinds of products of matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
k & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$ where $k>0$;

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$ where $\lambda = 1$;

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$ where $b$ is inclusive of all complex numbers;

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I am a little confused how to utilize these products to prove that every matrix in $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$ is a product of matrices of these four kinds

Comment: Elementary row operations?

Comment: I added the "matrices" and "linear-algebra" tags to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: Should that be $\lambda = -1$? Otherwise the second type is redundant and in fact these 4 types will not be sufficient.

Comment: Also, "scalar multiple" of what? The isomorphism is between what two groups?

Comment: It's true $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C)/\mathrm(SL)(2,\mathbb C) \cong \mathbb{C}^*$. Do you mean that every matrix in $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$ is a scalar multiple of a matrix in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$? ($\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ denotes the group of $2\times 2$ complex matrices of determinant 1.)

Comment: I thought our OP meant $\vert \lambda \vert = 1$, that is, $\lambda = e^{i\theta}$.  With $\lambda = 1$ you just get the identity matrix!

Comment: *Are* you sure you want $\lambda = 1$?  Maybe, instead, $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ where $\vert \lambda \vert = 1$?